# Understanding Two Nabla Operator

Tags: tensors, dirac-delta

I am currently taking an electrodynamics course and we are getting prepared with the maths needed.

In the section involving Dirac $\delta$-function, my lecturer writes out such an equation:

$\nabla\nabla\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}=-\frac{\vec{\vec{I}}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^3}+3\frac{(\vec{r}-\vec{r'})(\vec{r}-\vec{r'})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^5}-\frac{4\pi}{3}\vec{\vec{I}}\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r'})$

I never studied tensor formally, and this equation seems a total stranger to me.

How is this equation derived?

Comment: You can think of $\nabla\nabla f$ as the gradient of each component of $\nabla f$, and so as a matrix $[\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}]$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3525923/11127